# Multi-Cam View Disappeared from Premiere CC

Tags: premiere, multi-camera

I'm relatively new to Premiere CC, and very new to multi-cam editing. Half an hour ago the "multi-camera" view disappeared. That's the view that shows my 2 camera angles, side by side, and one of them is bordered in yellow. It should be to the left of my "composite" image on the top-right, but now there's just a black rectangle.

The footage I'm editing IS a multi-camera sequence.  I DO have "Multi-Camera" selected as the view.

So any ideas how I get it back?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I figured it out. Look at the timeline in the picture in my original question. Next to the multi-camera track, the "V1" is not selected. I selected that, and the multi-camera view came back. (I thought the "V1" just indicated which track a clip would be pasted to! Guess not.)

[image]

Comment: The video track "selection" applies not only to what's being used for multicam, but almost everything, including (most notably) what clips get split when you hit Ctrl + K and, as you already mentioned, where a clip gets pasted after copying. The same is true for the audio clip selection.